# ASP.NET MVC5: live loaded partial view doesn't load dynamic Javascript reference

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

My goal is to refresh a partial View containing an interactive world map.
I have a Controller action

`public JavaScriptResult DynMap(int id, List<int> relevantCountries = null){}`

which returns the map data as `JavaScriptResult`.

I call this Javascript in my Partial View "MapSite" with

```
<script src="/JS/DynMap/@ViewBag.GameRoomID"></script>
```

The Partial View "MapSite"

```
public ActionResult MapSite(int id)
{
   ViewBag.GameRoomID = id;
   return PartialView("MapSite");
}
```

is rendered into my main page like this:

```
<td id="map">
    @{Html.RenderAction("MapSite", "JS");}
</td>
```

That works perfectly fine!
But if I want to render MapSite again at runtime (with new values) like this: `$('#map').load('/JS/MapSite/4')`(4 is static for testing), the Partial View comes without the DynMap Javascript.

Is this a bug? Isn't it possible to load external Javascript this way "live"?
It even hits the breakpoint inside the Controller DynMap method, but the map is empty, because the DynMap values are missing.

Comment: Could you not use ajax and pass a parameter as well?

Comment: I had a similar issue when using @ajax.actionlinks, I found it easier to reference the needed script on the main page and execute a callback on success/error/complete.

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

I found out that my approach is working perfectly fine!
The problem was in MY specific case that the Javascript content was loaded **after** the html page itself. So the window.onload() inside the Javascript couldn't be executed and I just had to do it manually afterwards.